# JsRender Deep Nested data templates

Tags: jsrender

Is there a way to retrieve a template that is stored in a child object (*AKA a child object stored in an array off of the parent object*), when doing a **for loop** and apply that template on the child object?

I know that question is a bit confusing.  Below is some code to make things clearer.

**The following constructor functions represent my model:**

```
function group (children) {
    this.children = children;
}
group.prototype.jsTmpl = $1_10_2.templates('<div class="group">{{for children tmpl=jsTmpl /}}</div>');
group.prototype.render = function(selector){
    $1_10_2(selector).html(this.jsTmpl.render(this));
}


function item (title) {
    this.title = title;
}
item.prototype.jsTmpl = $1_10_2.templates('<div class="item">{{:title}}</div>');
```

I am storing the unique jsRender template in the prototype of each object so I can easily access it when dealing with recursive data.  Here I am newing up a 'group' object with four 'item' object children:

```
var vehicles = new group([
        new item('car'),
        new item('truck'),
        new item('van'),
        new item('bus'),
    ]);
```

Now when I call **vehicles.render();** on my vehicles group instance I would expect the following:

```
Output: <div class="group">
            <div class="item">car</div>
            <div class="item">truck</div>
            <div class="item">van</div>
            <div class="item">bus</div>
        </div>
```

Instead I get the following:

```
Output: <div class="group">
            <div class="group"></div>
            <div class="group"></div>
            <div class="group"></div>
            <div class="group"></div>
        </div>
```

I have come to the conclusion that **tmpl=jsTmpl** in the **group** object is always referencing the **group** object's jsTemp property, not the current child in the for loop.

I have tried to use the following for the group jsRender template:

```
'<div class="group">{{for children}}{{include tmpl=jsTmpl}}{{/for}}</div>'
```

but jsRender does not like having an include inside of a for loop.

Is there any way to get the child's template and apply it in a parent's for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Nice approach.

You are missing the closing slash on {{include}}. Otherwise it should work fine.

`<div class="group">{{for children}}{{include tmpl=jsTmpl}/}}{{/for}}</div>`

Comment: @Matt Dempsey: Did you see this? Can you confirm that it works for you now?